# Solr highlights shorter similar words

Tags: java, search, solr, search-engine, solrj

Looking for some help in pointing me in the right direction. I am new user to SOLR and am using solrj to pull data back from the search engine.

Everything seems to work fine except the highlighting not working as expected. If I search for the word **Operational**, I do get hits on the word **operational** but they are not highlighted. The only words that are highlighted are **Operation**.

Same thing happens with the following words:

- Commander ---> command is highlighted
- Personal  ---> person is highlighted
- Understanding  --> understand is highlighted
- developmental --> development is highlighted
- operational --> operation is highlighted

Another thing I noticed was 4 or 5 letter words have not problem being highlighted when searched for, just the longer words.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This highlighting behavior is due to the use of a [Stemmer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#English) in your `fieldType` for the field against which you are requesting highlights. When you query for **operational** the stemmer is reducing the word down to **operation** and finding the highlight against that term. I would recommend having a separate field with a field type that does not include a stemmer and return highlighting for that field.